# gdb-multiarch: debugging x64 program on aarch64 does not recognize dynamic functions

Tags: c, gdb

I am working on an arm64 machine and trying to debug a x64 program. I installed gdb, gdb-multiarch, the x64 compiler, the x64 libc. I have a basic program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello from qemu\n");
}
```

Compiled with `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -o main main.c`
I run it using `qemu-x86_64 -g 1234 main` then start `gdb-multiarch` with

```
file main
target remote localhost:1234
```

The main function looks like this:

```
gef➤  disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000004000001135 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000004000001136 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000004000001139 <+4>: lea    rdi,[rip+0xec4]        # 0x4000002004
   0x0000004000001140 <+11>:    call   0x4000001030
   0x0000004000001145 <+16>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000000400000114a <+21>:    pop    rbp
   0x000000400000114b <+22>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

The printf function is not recognized, and most gef commands do not work, for example `got` or any heap command:

```
gef➤  got
[!] Command 'got' failed to execute properly, reason: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: Missing debug info? Try adding `-g` to your compile command.

Comment: @ssbssa I am referring to the libc functions, that should be recognized whether symbols are enabled or not. On same arch as the CPU it works fine